# Cannot import module python ImportError

Tags: python, importerror, flask-restful

I have a project with this structure (showing only with the affected):

```
main.py # starting script
/app
  |__init__.py
  |/exceptions
    | __init__.py # content: from .ex400 import *
    | base.py
    | ex400.py # content: some classes extending classes from base.py
  |/extend
    | __init__.py # empty
    | module.py
```

from `/app/extend/module.py`, I trying to import classes from `/app/exceptions/ex400.py`. And from main I imported module.py

module.py

```
# I added this to check the path, output is below
import sys
print 'Working directory =>', sys.path

from app.exceptions.ex400 import SomeClass, MoreClass

# ... some code here ofcourse
```

And when running, I get an `ImportError`.

```
Working directory => ['/prj/myproject', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

...
File "/prj/myproject/app/extend/module.py", line 5, in <module>
   from app.exceptions.ex400 import SomeClass, MoreClass
ImportError: No module named exceptions.ex400
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are missing something. Its just something little but importing with Python is a pain in the a** anyways. For example you do not have an `__init__.py` in you *app*-folder. That should fix your issue. And by the way to not get confused over namespaces etc. I would simply leave the `__init__.py` in your *exceptions*-folder empty.

Cheers

Comment: Im sorry!, i really missed that in my question, but i have that hehe sorry!, ill edit

Comment: That is weird, I recreated your structure an it works on my machine...Any typos maybe? (Silly suggestion but you know) Also, what is the contents of your `__init__.py` in _app_folder? And the contents of main.py?

Comment: it is weird! i have spent like ours for this sh**.. I dont think typo is the cause, because when i use the relative import `from ..exceptions.ex400 import Class` it works..

Comment: Okay, so I know it is bad practice (for StackOverflow) but I uploaded my structure so you can download and check it. [Download my structure.](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11448630/tmp.rar.html) Please report back if this works and if so, what the problem was, since it is very likely that that file won't be up for long.

Comment: Please compare the included files and tell us how they differed!

Comment: by structure, ours dont differ.

Comment: Do they by contents?

Comment: if by contents you mean the way they are immported, then yes they are.

Comment: yes.. wtf haha. ill use relative import for now until i find out why this sh** is happening to me.. thanks @Krazor !